# how can i search few features inside a matrix

Tags: matlab

I am trying to do some simple combination, I have a Matrix of X consists of 2000 variables and a Y I want to each time pick 4 of the variables from X and make a regression and keep only those sets that have higher R than 0.9 . I found another solution based on 3 matrices, what want is one matrix and I tried to amend the code but somewhat I did not get it right

This is what I have tried

```
tic
X1 = rand(100,2000);
Y  = rand(100,1);
in = ones(100,1);
R = zeros(size(:,1),1);
for c = 1:size(:,1)
    X    = [in X1(:,i)];
    yhat = X*(X\Y);
    ybar = mean(Y);
    ssr  = norm(yhat - ybar)^2;  
    sst  = norm(Y - ybar)^2; 
    R(c) = ssr/sst;
end
toc
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear (what do you do with `Y`?) and your code is invalid, but perhaps you're looking for [`nchoosek`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html).

Comment: @beaker thanks for your message. Every time we select 4 variables of X and then make a regression between Y and those 4 variables. Then calculate R and if it is higher than 0.9 then we mention it in another file which variables were good. if they are not good, it goes for another set. this is what i am trying to do , is it clear?  for the `nchoosek`I don't know how to use it in this context, have you got any idea?

Comment: You have 2000 variables and you want to choose combinations of 4 of them at a time. The second function signature of `nchoosek` allows you to pass a vector, say [1:2000], and it will return all combinations taking `k` of those vector elements, say 4, at at time.

Comment: @beaker please make any solution, I would definitely accept it